# Ionic 2 view updates become slow

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm building an app using Ionic 2 involving a timer.
When the timer starts everything is fine and the updates are instant. However, in Ionic View, the view updates become slower and slower. The timeout is set to 32ms, but after the timer has run for 3 minutes, the updates are about very second. I also tested by running it as an Android app. The updates become slower and slower as well, but not as slow as with Ionic View. The weird thing is that when I touch the screen, the updates are instant again, until I release it.

How can I solve this?

I start the timer using

```
this.timer = setInterval(self.getUpdate(self), 32);
```

The getUpdate function

```
getUpdate(self) {
    return () => {
        self.lapTime = TimerPage.formatTime(new Date().getTime() - self.startTime);
        self.cd.markForCheck();
    };
}
```

In the view I simply use this to display the time

```
<div>{{lapTime}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As it's not clear what seems to be causing the trouble and nobody has suggested anything in 5 hours.*

**Possible Cause:**

Angular uses **zone.js** for `change detection`

Which keeps track of all `Asynchronous` events and provides hooks

and Angular uses these hooks to `Re-render` the view.

Which could be bit heavy if it's triggered every `32ms`

### `Solution:`

<strike>file an issue on Angular's Github Account</strike>

run your `setInterval` out of `zone.js`'s scope like this

```ts
import {Component, NgZone} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({})
export class YourClass{
  constructor(public zone:NgZone){}

  setSetInterval(self){ //just a random, normal function

    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(
      //anything done here won't trigger a change detection

      this.timer = setInterval(self.getUpdate(self), 32); 
    )
  }

  getUpdate(self){
    this.zone.run(
      //to reenter the angular's parent zone and trigger a change detection

      //put your functions functionality in here
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Then again, it's weird that it does work once I touch the screen.
I removed the markForCheck() call and it appears to be slowing down much slower. After that I also increased the interval a little. Now it updates at a speed I can live with. Thanks!

Comment: there is one more possible reason, Browser might have something to slow down or `debounce` mechanism `for too many iterations`, which is also just a guess in the air.

Comment: May have to come back on that. It still becomes very slow, with the update interval set to 100ms, the view is updated only once every 3 seconds after it ran for about 20min. I also tested this on an iPhone (using Ionic View) and it doesn't seem to be affected by this, it keep going at full speed. So it probably it the Android webview that causes it.

Comment: Did you enable production mode before perfomance tests https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6189 ?